# Salesforce Mobile SDK React Native: Invoke Biometric/Pin Prompt after timeout in react native app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, react-native

Mobile-SDK version: v10.0.0

Platform: android, iOS

React Native: 0.67.1

We are developing a react native app using salesforce SDK and have a requirement where we want the user to enter his/her pin/biometric after few minutes of inactivity.

Right now we have added the config in connected app to enable pin prompt, after which the mobile app asks user to provide device pin/biometric on login and every time when app is brought to foreground. We need to enhance this feature so that we can show the same prompt to user after few minutes of inactivity.

We looked into ways to programmatically invoke the pin prompt but right now it is not supported as per this [github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-ReactNative/issues/272)

Please suggest solutions to help us with above use case. Thanks you in advance.